# What are the effects of different wire lengths on a single Ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, wiring

Typically the wire lengths inside an Ethernet cable are all relatively equal. I know there must be some slight variance between the length of the individual wires inside cable due to some twisting around more than others but what about lengths greater than 1 meter? Do length differences between pairs of wires only matter at that point or do all have to be relatively the same length in order for the cable to function properly?

The main reason why I ask this is because I have a strange scenario where I have 2 Ethernet cables going from my network closet inside the house to the a network box outside the house (where ISPs can connect to it). Each of the 2 cables have wires inside them that aren't functioning properly so I can't use them individually but between all the wires between the 2 cables, I should be able to frankenstein a "single cable". In this scenario, the two cables forming a single cable should be roughly the same length but, depending on how everything is routed through the walls, the wire lengths between this frankenstein'd cable could vary by a few meters.

Would the cable function the same as any other cable or would timings of the signals or some other phenomena make this function not work as expected?

Comment: My guess is that provided the chosen wires are in twisted pairs they will work in practice, although maybe not at optimum speed or in a standards compliant way.  I also expect that the longer the run and lower the cat rating the more problematic performance might be.

Comment: Are you aware that you can run 100 megabit Ethernet over only 2 pairs? (Similarly you can run 2*100 megabit drops or 1*100 megabit + up to 2*phone through 1 standard cat 5 or better 4 pair cable)

Comment: @davidgo I am aware. The problem in this scenario is that I should be getting 1 gigabit (or close to it) but because of the broken wires I am only able to get the 100 megabit speeds. From what I understand, gigabit speeds require all 8 pairs.

Comment: @davidgo Thanks for your insight. When I end up attempting this, I will try to ensure that the pairs at least come from the same cable and hope for the best

Comment: You would be much better off pulling new cables...

Comment: @DavidPostill I 100% agree with you but there is no conduit from point A (downstairs, outside, single floor portion of the house) to point B (upstairs, middle, 2 story portion of the house). Without conduit, the cables are just stapled to 2x4s and I don't even want to think of the potential nightmare of a path they could've taken from point A to B. It could cost a lot or be not ideal to route a different way. Getting off topic though as the question is mostly about the theoretical, technical problem with a real world example to back up the question's validity.